# Oodle PHP XML request returns nothing

Tags: php, xml, api, debugging, rest

I have found very little documentation on this API so I have came here with the hopes that someone knows how to use this thing. When I try this nothing shows up. For now I am just trying to display the title of the first listing. Here is my code:

```
 <?php
            $url = "http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=MYKEY&region=sf&category=sale/electronics&q=ipod";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $response->element[0]->title;
    ?>
```

And here is a link to the XML: http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle/car

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the XML before you can access it like that.

Something like the following (untested!)

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=MYKEY&region=sf&category=sale/electronics&q=ipod";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo $xmlDoc->element[0]->title;
?>
```

In this example I'm using [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

In simpler terms, by doing `$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($response)` we're telling PHP that `$response` contains XML that should be parsed into structures that can be programmatically accessed.

In this case `$xmlDoc` becomes a `SimpleXMLElement` object, that you can use as per documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php